# Taking LocalTime input in jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on a spring boot and hibernate project

One of my entity class has a localDate and localTime both for different purposes

```
 public class User{
     
     private LocalTime dailyStartTime;
     
     private LocalDate UniversityStartDate;

     //There are other fields here as well
 }
```

My jsp form looks like this

```
 <frm:form modelAttribute="user">
    <frm: input type="time" path="dailyStartTime">
    <frm: input type="date" path="UniversityStartDate">
 </frm:form
```

Using @InitBinder, I am able parse the date and the date gets updated in the user object.

but I am not able to parse the time getting error as typeMismatch (Failed to convert property value of String to LocalTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There just was a similar question here [JpaRepository SQL syntax error when trying to save to MySQL Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913295/jparepository-sql-syntax-error-when-trying-to-save-to-mysql-date/64915748#64915748).

For the form binding you probably need to add `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` and `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH-mm")`. However it's good practice to separate the data object from the actual entities, otherwise you may get problems persisting with the new attributes.