# JpaRepository SQL syntax error when trying to save to MySQL Date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jpa

I have the following row in my MySQL Table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0FC4.png

This column is represented as:

```
    @Column(name="release")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate release;
```

And it is bound to a Thymeleaf form like so:

```
    <label for="release">Release date</label>
    <input type="date" 
      th:field="*{movie.release}"
      th:value="*{movie.release}"
      id="release" 
      class="form-control mb-3">
```

Now if I **insert a date** into the MySQL db directly, the date is loaded and set to the correct date on the form:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e35lr.png
But every time I try to save or edit the movie I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release='2016-05-19', title='The Shawshank Redemption', user_name='susan' where ' at line 1

Even if I set the release date to null Hibernate won't save the movie.
If I completely remove the @Column for the date and remove it from the Thymeleaf form, the object is saved properly without errors. Because JpaRepository is generating all the queries I can't see how the Syntax could be wrong. I've also tried with standard java.util.Date as the type with the same issue.

EDIT: Removing the @DateTimeFormat gives the following error:

> [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'movie.release']

Using Spring Boot 2.3.5.RELEASE

Comment: Can you try removing the @DateTimeFormat? Basically the mapping should work without problems with the current Spring / Hibernate / JDBC versions. Maybe you have some weird config?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your reply, deleting that annotation now gives the following error:  [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'movie.release']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the column name in MySQL - **release** is a protected word and causes issues with the query when used. Should have noticed when I tried to drop the column, as it would not auto-fill the name like it does for other columns...

Answer (score 0):

According to your feedback, remoing `@DateTimeFormat` resolves the issue with the database mapping - so this is the first thing.

Next I would recommend to separate the data transfer objects used for the forms from the actual entities. It will help a lot in the long run. So you have a `MovieDTO` for form binding, where you can put `@DateTimeFormat` and other form validations like `@NotNull`. Then you will need to map the movieDto object to the movie entity before persisting.

Comment: Tidied up the Movie class and added a MovieDTO class as suggested, and mapping using ModelMapper. Though now the two problems are shifted, depending on whether @DateTimeFormat is on the LocalDate field in MovieDTO or not.

Comment: What is the error, when @DateTimeFormat is on the MovieDTO class (and not on the entity? On which step does the error occur?

Comment: The same SQL Syntax error when the Movie object is being saved (I can print the MovieDTO/Movie objects prior to saving them). With the DateTimeFormat removed its the following: >[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'movieDTO.release'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDate] for value '2020-11-05'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2020-11-05]

Comment: But in the second case, your error is pointing to the movieDTO, so it's a problem with binding. You have the field @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") private LocalDate release; present on the MovieDTO?

Comment: Yes the DateTimeFormat is on the DTO field when it shows the SQL Syntax error, or I remove the annotation and get the binding error.

Comment: Mhm sorry, I think there is another problem when mapping the LocalDate to SQL - usually this should work out-of-the box. I don't know your config / project setup. Maybe you can create a small project on https://bootify.io with MySQL and compare with your config?